# numpy broadcast multiply on condition?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays, one of shape `arr1.shape = (1000,2)` and the other of shape `arr2.shape = (100,)`.

I'd like to somehow multiply `arr1[:,1]*arr2` where `arr1[:,0] == arr2.index` so that I get a final shape of `arr_out.shape = (1000,)`. The first column of arr1 is essentially an *id* where the following condition holds true: `set(arr1[:,0]) == set(i for i in range(0,100))`, i.e. there is always at least one value index of `arr2` found in `arr1[:,0]`.

I can't quite see how to do this in the numpy library but feel there should be a way using [numpy multiply](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html), if there was a way to configure the *where* condition correctly?

I considered perhaps a dummy index dimension for `arr2` might help?

A toy example can be produced with the following code snippet

```py
arr2_length = 100
arr1_length = 1000

arr1 = np.column_stack(
    (np.random.randint(0,arr2_length,(arr1_length)),
     np.random.rand(arr1_length))
)
arr2 = np.random.rand(arr2_length)

# Doesn't work
arr2_b = np.column_stack((
    np.arange(arr2_length),
    np.random.rand(arr2_length)
))
# np.multiply(arr1[:,1],arr2_b[:,1], where=(arr1[:,0]==arr2_b[:,0]))
```

One sort of solution I had was to leverage a left join in Pandas to broadcast the smaller array to a same-lengthed array and then multiply, as follows:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(arr1).set_index(0).join(pd.DataFrame(arr2))
arr_out = (df[0]*df[1]).values
```

But I'd really like to understand if there's a native numpy way of doing this since I feel using dataframe joins for a multiplication isn't a very readable solution and possibly suffers from excess memory overhead.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Technically this isn't a `broadcasting` issue; it's an indexing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.random.randint(1, 5, (10, 2))
arr2 = np.random.randint(1, 5, (5,))

arr2_sampled = arr2[arr1[:, 0]]

result = arr1[:, 1]*arr2_sampled
```

Output:

```
arr1 = 
[[4 2]
 [3 3]
 [2 3]
 [3 1]
 [2 1]
 [2 4]
 [1 1]
 [4 2]
 [4 1]
 [3 4]]

arr2 = 
[4 1 2 1 2]

arr2_sampled = 
[2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1]

result = 
[4 3 6 1 2 8 1 4 2 4]
```

Comment: This is perfect thankyou! I hadn't considered broadcasting in this way, it's very useful. Thankyou for illustrating the output.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this does exactly what you want:

```
indices, values = arr1[:,0].astype(int), arr1[:,1]
arr_out = values * arr2[indices]
```

Comment: This is perfect thankyou! I hadn't considered broadcasting in this way, it's very useful.